# For accessibility, In html what should I use to label non form control data?

Tags: html, accessibility

The w3c defines a label as:

> The <label> element represents a caption in a user interface

It then goes on to say

> The caption can be associated with a specific form control

Strictly speaking form controls are buttons, check boxes, radio buttons, menus, text input, file select, hidden controls or object tags.

My question is, in the interest of accessibility what is best practise for representing a caption for just plain read only information.  I don't want to use an input, I only want to display.  Should I just use headings?  Is there anything in ARIA to help?

For example

```html
<label>Primary question
  <div>What should I use to caption plain old informtion?</div>
</label>
<label>Potential answer
  <div>Just use headings</div>
</label>
<label>Date asked
  <div>10/01/2016</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Just use paragraphs?

Comment: @BoltClock You may be right.  It just didn't feel right.  Paragraphs felt more like copy content.  My original form is for some council tax data, i.e. caption: amount type data.  Maybe my example isn't the best.  Let me add something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I take your example, you use a perfect understandable sentence. You have no need to format anything for a screenreader. Also you can use specific markup; this can targets both sighted people with visual aid, and blind people with specific intonations

> **Primary question**: “What should I use to caption plain old information?”
>
> **Potential answer**: “Just use plaind old text.”

```
<strong>Primary question</strong>:
<quote>What should I use to caption plain old information?</quote>
<strong>Potential answer</strong>:
<quote>Just use plaind old text.</quote>
```

In fact, the biggest part of your example is how you should write the date in order to make it clear that it's the 10th of january or the first of october.

> Date asked: 10/01/2016

This is not helping accessibility and the best choice would be to use the full formal date:

> Date asked: October `<abbr aria-label="First" title="First">1st</abbr>,` 2016

In the above example, I explicited the "1st" abbrevation both providing a tooltip and an aria-label for this commonly used abbreviation.

**EDIT**: To answer one of my favorite reader, you can understand why we chose to use the `strong` element to markup the question by refering to the W3C documentation for [the b element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element).

> The b element should be used as a last resort when no other element is more appropriate. In particular, headings should use the h1 to h6 elements, stress emphasis should use the em element, importance should be denoted with the strong element, and text marked or highlighted should use the mark element.

Here we want to denote importance in a text which is not a heading. Using headings to markup question can be applicable if the question text does convey information for the document structure (within a FAQ page for instance which might be the case here). But in a general context, for a single element, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Headings could be used, as screen reader support is good for them. However the association of a heading with the content below it is implied rather than strictly designated.

From a semantic html stance a definition list may be preferable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl provides examples of definition lists where the dt and dd tags are used to associate key/value pairs which should meet your use case. Unfortunately screen readers do not necessarily expose the correct semantics of the definition list.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/definition-lists-v-tables provides examples of screen reader tests and finds the definition list support in screen readers deficient. That article recommends the use of tables with scope attributes on header cells, as a better supported solution.

Comment: Nice answer in the context of a FAQ page (which we ignore but we might guess). To be complete, you should also specify that if there are cases where headings can be used (which would suppose some kind of importance in the document structure), they must not be used if the only goal is to make some kind of presentational effect.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if textarea is suitable? I know I said I didn't want to use inputs but I wonder if the following is a good answer or not?

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

textarea, input {
  display: block;
}

textarea[readonly], input[readonly] {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Primary question
  <textarea readonly>What should I use to caption plain old informtion?'</textarea>
</label>
<label>Potential answer
  <textarea readonly>use readonly textareas?</textarea>
</label>
<label>Date asked
  <input readonly value='10/01/2016' />
</label>
<label>Editable comment
  <input/>
</label>
```